# Multiple Directives in the same view not working / Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call a directive two times in the same view. I have the following error when i load the page :

> ```
> ionic.bundle.js:21162Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [translate (module: pascalprecht.translate),mwConfirmClick] asking for new/isolated scope on:
> ```

My directive :

```
app.directive( "mwConfirmClick", [
function( ) {
    return {
        priority: -1,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { confirmFunction: "&mwConfirmClick" },
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
            element.bind( 'click', function( e ){
                // message defaults to "Are you sure?"
                var message = attrs.mwConfirmClickMessage ? attrs.mwConfirmClickMessage : "Are you sure?";
                // confirm() requires jQuery
                if( confirm( message ) ) {
                    scope.confirmFunction();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Could you help me please to set my directive ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using two directives with a isolate scope (`scope: {...}`) not just in the same view but on the same element. your element probably looks something like this:

```
<p mw-confirm-click="..." translate="..." ...></p>
```

you either have to remove one of the directives with the isolate scope (`mw-confirm-click` or the `translate` directive) or you have to remove the isolate scope from your directive and use the variables from the parent scope...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the translate directive and it works. Thanks